# how to show a treeview style in WPF?

Tags: wpf

my input

```
   Sore | aye
    A    |   1 
    A    |   2
    A    |   3
    B    |   1
    B    |   2
```

OutPut:   and I want to sort the top table into the underneath treeview

```
A
   1 
   2 
   3
B  
   1
   2
```

Comment: Please don't use version tags anyhow unless you know what version of C# you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets assume you have class called `Table` containing two properties `list<string> Sore` and `List<int> aye`

```
public class Table
{
    public String Sore { get; set; }
    public int Aye { get; set; }
}

var table = new List<Table>
                {
                    new Table{  Sore = "A" , Aye = 1},
                    new Table{  Sore = "A" , Aye = 2},
                    new Table{  Sore = "A" , Aye = 3},
                    new Table{  Sore = "B" , Aye = 1},
                    new Table{  Sore = "B" , Aye = 2},
                };
var group = table.GroupBy(q => q.Sore).ToList();
foreach (var g in group)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(g.Key);
    foreach (var i in g)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("   "+i.Aye);
    }
}
```

the Output will be:

```
A
   1
   2
   3
B
   1
   2
```